# Why is VLC player not working while fullscreen?

Tags: vlc

While I am playing a video it is running smoothly in normal window. But when I am in fullscreen mode the video is not playing anymore. There are two things happening:

1. The video is stopped
2. There is no video at all

But in both cases the sound is ok...
What is the problem?

Comment: Which model Pi ? Are you using the latest Raspbian Buster fully updated? What video file are you playing?

Comment: I am using Pi4 . And yes I am using Buster with recommanded softwares ROM.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the important additional information you have been asked to the question. You should also tag it.

Answer (score 4):

Tools->Preferences->Video: Output:=X11 videooutput XBC
helped for me.

[image]

Comment: Where are tools? You should explain your solution a bit more.

Comment: Also, adding screen shots would improve your answer.

Comment: You can find Tools in the menu in the upper row in VLC, or press Alt+S.
To reach Preferences you can directly press Ctrl+P.
(Englich GUI assumed.)

Answer (score 1):

I've switched the HDMI output port on my Raspberry Pi 4 B and it was solved.

Credit to this reddit comment - https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/g1vre1/need_help_rpi_4b_vlc_fullscreen/

Comment: This worked on my rPi 400 too ... but why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the codec. I chamged it to HDPAU and everything was okay.

Comment: If this solved your problem, @Sohan Arafat, please 'accept' this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out that setting the GPU memory via raspi-config was the solution.  I had it at the default of 64, I set it to 256 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the command line option:-

--mmal-display hdmi-2